# Can I preload custom fonts on iPhone to improve performance?

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, uifont

I've added the `UIAppFonts` entry on my info.plist to enable custom ttf fonts, it works fine.  However when using the font there's also a delay in the UIView the first time it's called, is there a way to preload the fonts or some other technique to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any solution or any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application delegate or some other place that is called when the application launches try creating a hidden UILabel that uses your custom font and remove it straight away. That way it will preload the font so that the next time you use a UILabel with that font it won't pay the first time penalty.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I should have pointed out I have tried something similar, which seems to help but there's still a slight delay on the second time (on for the users experience, the first).  I've tried to initiate a label with the text 'ABCDEDGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890' which seems to help further, so I suppose it has to be tricked a bit better rather than being a actual way iOS can embed the font into a view / controller